# A weird png photo (can only open in Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, png

[enter link description here](http://gsl.xiyoukeji.com/Uploads/2017-01-25/3_5888792c5d3260.png)

Here is this weird png. If you download it or open it in safari or edge, it will fail. It can only be open in chrome? Do anyone know why this png cannot open in local or other browsers and why chrome can open it? Thanks.